# How can I create a dynamically changing cloud-shaped sheech-bubble in Android XML

Tags: android

Im developing the messages part of my android app and I want to differentiate the messages of the user and their correspondent using a speech bubble that dynamically changes size to wrap the content inside

[image]

But I have no idea how to do that, I mean the thin part at one of the ends.

Comment: Thank you! I watched this video on Nine patches http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfrXE2R2nqM and now I have an expanding speech bubble. If you provide nine patch as an answer, I'd accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you posted is a good candidate to be used as a `nine-patch` image because it allows you to put stretchable portions on it without affecting the image's actual look. This will make the image to wrap content of any size, you goal as you mentioned in the question. Related to this you can read about the [`nine-patch` tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).